# How do I load the address dynamically in an embedded google map?

Tags: angularjs, google-maps, iframe, dynamic

Bear with me please, because I am a N00b.
I am creating an Ionic app with Firebase and AngularJS.
What I am trying to do is have a map load with the address location drawn from the database. (Being hard-coded is not an option)  I can do this as an external link like this:

```
<a href="http://maps.google.com/?q={{task.street}}, {{task.city}}, {{task.zip}}">See Location</a>
```

and it works, but it opens up to the web page google maps (which isn't practical for an app)
So, I have tried embedding the map in an iframe like this:

```
 <iframe
         ng-controller="BrowseCtrl"
         width="100%"
         height="450px"
         frameborder="0" style="border:0"
         src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed/v1/place?q={{task.street}}, {{task.city}}, {{task.zip}}&key=xxxxxxxx" allowfullscreen>
       </iframe>
```

but I can't get it to work.  My guess is because the iframe is "outside" of the page and not recognizing the dynamic data.  Does anyone know how I can load the address dynamically into an embedded map, or is there a better way to do this using AngularJS?  Ideally, I would like to have all the functions available in the app itself, even if this means having to go to a payed service.  For now, though, I am trying to simply embed the map.

Thanks in advance!

**Update1**

I haven't found the fix yet, but I think I found the problem. In the console there is an error saying: "a trusted value is required" and then links to this, docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$sce I will have to read over this and get back

**Update 2**

I added this to the Controller:

```
$scope.trustedURL = $sce.trustAsResourceUrl("https://www.google.com/maps/embed/v1/place?q={{task.street}}, {{task.city}}, {{task.zip}}&key=xxxxxxx");
```

And changed the html to this:

```
 <iframe

     width="100%"
     height="450px"
     frameborder="0" style="border:0"
     ng-src="{{trustedURL}}" allowfullscreen>
   </iframe>
```

This fixed the error "a trusted value is required", but I am still getting the same result - a map with a randomly generated location.   It's not recognizing the dynamically loaded data in {{}}. Any thoughts???

Comment: Have you tried building the whole URL and using that as the src?  i.e. src="{{mapURL}}" ?

Comment: I don't think that would work.  The street address, city, and zip are all separate fields in the database.  They are entered by outside users in a form, not by an administrator, and that information gets stored in the database.  When the page is pulled with the data, the map should also show their location

Comment: I haven't found the fix yet, but I think I found the problem.  In the console there is an error saying: "a trusted value is required" and then links to this,
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$sce
I will have to read over this and get back.

Comment: I have had a bit of a search & found a few places where people are using the Google maps API on jsFiddle, but not using an iFrame, so not sure that would help

Answer (score 0):

Try to use [ng-src](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngSrc) instead of *src*

```
 <iframe
         ng-controller="BrowseCtrl"
         width="100%"
         height="450px"
         frameborder="0" style="border:0"
         ng-src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed/v1/place?q={{task.street}}, {{task.city}}, {{task.zip}}&key=xxxxxxxx" allowfullscreen>
  </iframe>
```

Comment: Unfortunately, it didn't make a difference.  I get a map, but with a randomly generated address.  It's not recognizing the variables being pulled from the database {{task.city}} etc.

Answer (score 0):

Use it like this:

```
<iframe
    ng-src="{{ 'https://www.google.com/maps/embed/v1/place?q=' + task.street + ',' + task.city + ',' + task.zip + '&key=xxxxxxxx' }}">
</iframe>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Step 1**

HTML Inside html use

```
 [src]=methodToGetURL()
```

methodToGetURL: a function which return httl url from component file

EXAMPLE- iframe

```
[src]="methodToGetURL()" allowfullscreen  /iframe'
```

Step 2) component file

Add DomSanitizer:

```
import {DomSanitizer} from '@angular/platform-browser';
```

function :

```
methodToGetURL() `enter code here`{
        return this.domSanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl('https:Your  URL here');
}
```